# Segmentation fault on specific set of input

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers

I'm trying to code this problem statement :

> "Given a positive integer N, find the number of positive integer divisors of N2 that are less than N, but do not divide N."

It is working well for small inputs, but when size of input increases, its throwing segmentation faults. Given below is code folewed by two test cases :

---

Code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    long int n,n2,j=0,count=0;
    cin>>n;
    n2=n*n;
    long arr[n];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n2%i==0)
        {
            arr[j]=i;
            j++;
        }
    }        
    
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
            if(n%arr[i]!=0)
            count++;
    }        
    cout<<count;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Case 1: (correct)

> 30
>
> 6

case 2:

> 2226020
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I don't see any reason why it should happen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Given N, what's N2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said you are 'overloading' the stack but I would recommend using std::vector instead of an array and avoid manual memory management.

```
long int n, n2, j = 0, count = 0;
cin >> n;
n2 = n * n;
vector<long> arr (n);
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (n2 % i == 0) {
        arr[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    if (n % arr[i] != 0)
        count++;
}
cout << count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is crashing because you are trying to create an array with ~ 8mb on stack.

Use the heap instead:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    long int n,n2,j=0,count=0;
    cin>>n;
    n2=n*n;

    long *arr = (long*) malloc(n);

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n2%i==0)
        {
            arr[j]=i;
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        if(n%arr[i]!=0)
        count++;
    }
    cout<<count;
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please no `malloc()` in C++ programs.